# core data relationship between entities

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, entity-relationship

hi i need to use coredata relations in my app. coredata relations is first tym for me. kindly guide me.

i need to have 2 entities "Products" and "reviews". for a single product there can be multiple reviews. i have 3 questions.

1) "product" entity is already containgin data. i need to add reviews to "reviews" entity later only. so how do i connect both the entities? the only thing common between both is the "product id".

2) if i delete a product how to delete all the reviews related to it from "reviews" entity.

3) can i delete the reviews without altering "products" entity

kindly help me.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between product and review is one to many.  So create a relationship between the 2 entities, also set set the delete rule for product entity to “cascade”, so that when a product entity is deleted, the corresponding reviews for the products also gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make `relation` for both entities and if you used `NSArrayController` to manage objected context you have to bind the `Content set` for the `review` to it's relation. 
then you can use the NSarraycontroller to control the objects that you added as `review` and delete them without affecting `product'`s objects.
Also,you have to bind managed objects as you app's delegate to manage Objected context.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. i created entity and cascade. but is there any sample program for this?

Comment: @cancerian, welcome my friend. this is not hard-coded you have to done what I say in Interface Builder(IB).
also, you can search apple documents for bindings of arrays and arraycontrollers.